# Unable to update Microsoft Azure Container Permissions via AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, azure

I am trying to dynamically add the permissions for an Azure Container by allowing the user to "check box" the permissions that they require. Then I am returning the form data with an Ajax call to my controller.

My method: `public JsonResult GenerateSasWithPermissions(int optRadio, int[] optCheck)` is correctly and successfully able to access the `AJAX` data. I am then trying to use `optCheck` to update the following code:

```
`var sasToken = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
{
    Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read

    //Permissions is a list of of what access to give a Azure Container

});`
```

The `.Read` is park of a `public enum SharedAccessBlobPermissions` klass. Which contains:

```
   [Flags]
public enum SharedAccessBlobPermissions
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     No shared access granted.
    None = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Read access granted.
    Read = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Write access granted.
    Write = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Delete access granted.
    Delete = 4,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     List access granted.
    List = 8,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Add access granted.
    Add = 16,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Create access granted.
    Create = 32
}
```

The format that my `AJAX` call is returning data to my controller is all integers. I am trying to just assign the values from `optCheck` to `Permissions` with something like:

`Permissions = 8` This does not work, also when I try to iterate over my array for optCheck - it does not seem to find `Permissions`. Does anyone have any idea of how to assign my values to the `Permissions` object?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

I figured out that the code was simply adding the total values and then doing some magic in the back end to present a more human friendly rendering. I simply added a `using System.Linq;` statement and added the following code for casting:

```
var sasToken = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
  {
     Permissions = (SharedAccessBlobPermissions)optCheck.Sum()
  });
```

Which takes the total sum of all the items that were checked off and finds the sum which is cast then `SharedAccessBlobPermission` handles the rest.